# How do I debug a Python module function conditional on a loop that calls it?

Tags: python, loops, debugging

I have a Python module called functions_from_module, with a function called function_inside_module I'd like to debug. In my application, function_inside_module is being used to process some data which is run in a loop. However, one data point is giving me problems, so I want to stop the loop specifically there and examine what the module does.

I must not be googling the right thing; I have also tried declaring the looping variables as global because I think that this has something to do with global variables not being available in a function's scope, but that didn't seem to work.

Here's the module:

```
#filename is functions_from_module.py
def function_inside_module():
    print("Before debug")
    #if i > 3 #I want to do something like this
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    print("After debug")
```

and the main script:

```
#filename is main_script.py
from functions_from_module import function_inside_module
#for i in range(5): #I want to do something like this
function_inside_module()
```

To execute I run python main_script.py in the command line.

If the lines that I want to run are uncommented (and the right indents provided beneath), then it returns NameError: name 'i' is not defined.

The workaround I've used is to redefine function_inside_module to take the argument i, but that seems messy to me.

Comment: That's not messy, that's the correct way to do it...

Comment: I see. I was just worried that if I did this in the future I'd forget to remove the argument, and then it would dangle unused in the function and confuse me later.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work around this with an optional parameter:

```
import pdb

def function_inside_module(i=None):
    print("Before debug")
    if i > 3:  # Debugging trace only
        pdb.set_trace()
    print("After debug")

--------------------

from functions_from_module import function_inside_module
for i in range(5):
    function_inside_module(i)
```

Now, you *can* forget to remove `i` from the function; it will default to `None`.

Also, `import` statements belong at the top of the module, not buried in the middle.  Putting an `import` inside a loop is a *bad* idea; you re-`import` every time through the loop; the conditional check leaves results that can be hard to trace.